# Given $p$ an odd prime, $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p^2}$ and $(a,p)=1$, how could we know that $(x,p)=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

If I have the congruence $$x^2 \equiv a \pmod {p^2}$$ where $p$ is an odd prime and $(a,p)=1$, how could I know that $(x,p)=1$?

Comment: Hint: What if $(x,p)\neq 1$?

Comment: hi, thanks for the hint, however it has not helped me, there is something I am not picking up on

Comment: Hint: What values can $(x,p)$ take?

Comment: I cant seem to work this out

Comment: Note that $(x,p) \mid p$ so there are only two choices for what $(x,p)$ could be...

Comment: Of course, (x,p) = p or (x,p) =1 . If (x,p)= p then x^2= 0 mod( p^2) hence (x,p) =1. Thanks for the help, I should have spotted this much ealier

Comment: The fact that $p$ is prime is irrelevant. So we show that if $x^2\equiv a \pmod{m^2}$ and $\gcd(a,m)=1$ then $\gcd(x,m)=1$.
From $x^2\equiv a \pmod{m^2}$ we obtain $x^2\equiv a \pmod{m}$. Now suppose that $x$ and $m$ are not relatively prime. Then some $d\gt 1$ divides $x$ and $m$. So $d$ divides $x^2$ and $m$. But $x^2=a+qm$ for some integer $q$, so $d$ divides $a$. This contradicts the fact that $\gcd(a,m)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, $\ x^n\equiv a\pmod {\!m},\ (a,m)=1\ \,\Rightarrow\,\ (x,m)=1$.

$x^n\equiv a\pmod {\!m}\!\iff\! x^n-a=mk\ $ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$.

Assume, for contr., $\ (x,m)\neq 1\ $ - i.e. $\ \exists q\in\Bbb P\ (\ q\mid x\ \text{ and }\ q\mid m\ )$.

$q\mid x,m\ \,\Rightarrow\,\ q\mid x^n-mk=a\ \,\Rightarrow\, \ q\mid x,m,a\ \,\Rightarrow\, \ (a,m)\ge q>1$, contr.