# Show if $(a,p)=1$ and $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p^2}$ then $(x,p)=1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose $(a,p)=1$ and $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p^2}$ then $(x,p)=1$

How can I show that this is the case?

If $(a,p)=1$ and $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$ then is also the case that $(x,p)=1$?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266283/given-p-an-odd-prime-x2-equiv-a-pmodp2-and-a-p-1-how-could-we-know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p^2},$ $$(x^2,p^2)=(a,p^2)$$

But $(a,p)=1\implies (a,p^2)=1$

Answer (score 1):

If $(x,p)\neq1$, then$p|x$, hence $p|a$ which contradicts.

Comment: why do you assume $p|x$ instead of $x|p$?

Comment: Because $p$ is prime, and $(x,p)\neq1$

Comment: But the OP does not say $\,p\,$ is prime. Nor does the proof does require that hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

$(x,p)\mid a=x^2\!+np^2\Rightarrow\,(x,p) = (x,\color{#c00}{p,a}) = 1\,$ by $\,\color{#c00}{(p,a)=1}$